# I want to add the request new password link

Tags: drupal-7

I want to add the request new password link in login block, I am using drupal7 please help me, I am not getting where can i find this login block?thanks in advance

Comment: by default drupal 7.x have user-login block display this block some where in your site this block have links create new account and Request new password link by default.

Answer (score 0):

Implement this hook in your template.php file

```
/**
* Implements hook_form_alter()
*/
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'user_login_block':
      $form['link'] = array('#markup' => l(t('Request new password'),'path'));
    break;
  }
}
```